# getrusage returning zeros in ru_utime.tv_usec and ru_utime.tv_sec

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arm, getrusage

For the following code getrusage returning zeros in `ru_utime.tv_usec` and `ru_utime.tv_sec`.

Code:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "sys/time.h"
#include "sys/resource.h"

int getr_return, who = RUSAGE_SELF;
struct rusage usage;

main()
{
    getr_return = getrusage(who, &usage);
    printf(" getr_return = %d\n", getr_return);

    printf(" time taken in seconds = %.61f\n", usage.ru_utime.tv_sec);
    printf(" time taken in seconds = %.61f\n", usage.ru_utime.tv_usec);


        Some_Mips_consuming_code().


        getr_return = getrusage(who, &usage);
        printf(" getr_return = %d\n", getr_return);

        printf(" time taken in seconds = %.61f\n", usage.ru_utime.tv_sec);
        printf(" time taken in seconds = %.61f\n", usage.ru_utime.tv_usec);

    exit;
 }
```

output:

```
getr_return = 0
time taken in seconds =  0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
time taken in seconds =  0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
getr_return = 0
time taken in seconds =  0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
time taken in seconds =  0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

Compiled code on `Linux version 2.6.18-308`

Ran executable on ARM board and it's `Linux version 3.8.1-2.0`

Comment: So what is your expected output?

Comment: Additional information:
I have tried putting code inbetween two getrusage() as well, but still got those values as zeroes.

getr_return = getrusage(who, &usage);
    printf(" getr_return = %d\n", getr_return);

    printf(" time taken in seconds = %.61f\n", usage.ru_utime.tv_sec);
    printf(" time taken in seconds = %.61f\n", usage.ru_utime.tv_usec);
some
getr_return = getrusage(who, &usage);
    printf(" time taken in seconds = %.61f\n", usage.ru_utime.tv_sec);
    printf(" time taken in seconds = %.61f\n", usage.ru_utime.tv_usec);

Comment: Add a long enough computation. Something taking at least half a second of CPU time.

Comment: Yes, I have done that I have added a high MIPS consuming Decoder but still the result is same.

Answer (score 1):

The user usage time is calculated between two instants of the logic to find out the time consumed which should have a start and end usage of timeval. Some thing like below sample,

```
 struct timeval start, end;
 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
 start = usage.ru_utime;
 /* Code to check the usage consumed */
 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
 end = usage.ru_utime;
```

`ru_utime` & `ru_stime` are of structures of type `timeval`. If you look its [declaration](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/time.h#L20) both members `tv_sec` & `tv_usec` are of type `long`. So change the format specifier when printing to `%ld`. Note when on success `getrusage()` returns `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Time measurement is limited in precision, resolution and accuracy. Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). Don't expect significant measures for computation less than e.g. half a second.

Often, CPU time measurement is done by counting [jiffies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiffie) or timer interrupts (related to `HZ` if you have one in your kernel).

Since you call [getrusage(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) at the beginning of your `main`, not much computing has happened before it (basically, only pre-`main` initialization in e.g. [`crt0.o`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0)). So you should expect it to be near zero.

You might try using [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) with `CLOCK_REALTIME` or `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`.